# Meteor - How to render script tags in triple brackets?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a simple document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "gQgFzrxCecXxzuCEq",
    "content" : "\n# 5. Bonus: Meteor SSL Configuration.\n\n<script>console.log('hello world');</script>\n<script src=\"https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/9877434.js\"></script>\n\n",
    "title" : "Node #5: Building a REST API with Restify and Monk"
}
```

When I try to render the content with `{{{content}}}`, `<script>` tags are not evaluated and do not even appear in the DOM (it seems that the triple brackets rendering removes them).

Here is the template:

```
<template name="JournalArticleContent">
  <div class="article-content article-content-complete">{{{content}}}</div>
</template>
```

To be even more precise, the script I'm trying to render is a gist:

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/28bf7505fe4c5b439da5.js"></script>
```

What can I do to ask Meteor to display and evaluate them?

Comment: can you show the template source you are using?

Comment: I suppose you have considered also to remove script from JSON and evaluate script in a Meteor handler like `Template.some.rendered`, is that possible in this case?

Comment: I've updated my answer. The script is a little gist and is included in the document content field (which comes from an editor). I'd like to find a way to ask Meteor to render it as the triple brackets seems to have no effect.

Comment: I thought GitHub doesn't allow using the code served by them on websites (they don't set the mime headers)

Comment: The thing is even a simple <script>console.log('hello');</script> is not rendered and displayed in the DOM with {{{content}}}.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by creating a server API (router) to respond the html as in your `content`. And use ajax call to get what you want in client side.

```
// server side
Meteor.router.add('/api/getContent', function(){
  // retrieve your "content" here ...
  return [200, YourContent];
});

// client side, just use ajax to retrieve your content
```

### Edit

You perhaps need to look at **BrowserPolicy** in case the content is from external source